# Irreducible finite Kolmogorov spaces

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

Is it true that irreducible finite Kolmogorov spaces of Krull dimension 1 are homeomorphic iff they are equipotent? I am trying to imagine how the specialization order would look like and it seems to me that it is true,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Note that if $x$ is maximal in the specialization order, then $\{x\}$ is open.  So if our space $X$ is irreducible, it must have exactly one maximal element $x$ in the specialization order (if there were more than one, they would give disjoint nonempty open sets). So every element $y\in X$ satisfies $y\leq x$.  Moreover, if $y,z\in X$ are distinct and distinct from $x$, $y\not\leq z$, since otherwise $y\leq z\leq x$ would make the dimension greater than $1$.  So if $X$ has $n$ elements, this completely determines the specialization order up to isomorphism: there is a greatest element $x$, and the other $n-1$ elements are below $x$ and incomparable to each other.

Comment: is it true that two irreducible spectral spaces of Krull dimension $1$ are homeomorphic iff equipotent (not necessarily finite)?

Comment: No, because the topology is no longer determined by the specialization order in the infinite case.  For instance, you could take two non-homeomorphic Stone spaces of the same cardinality and adjoin a generic point to each of them.

Comment: but if both spaces are additionally Noetherian, then is it true?

Comment: Yes, a Noetherian spectal space is determined by its specialization order.